# NodeJS: createCipheriv should give same output like earlier createCipher

Tags: node.js, cryptography, cryptojs

Currently, I am using an old version of the crypto.js to encrypt and decrypt the strings. 
 Below is my code for encryption -

```
const encrypt = (password, algorithm, encMethod) => (value) => {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
  return cipher.update(JSON.stringify(value), 'utf8', encMethod)
    + cipher.final(encMethod);
};
```

Using the above code my string (E-mailID) 
 `p1@yopmail.com` is converted to 
 `29c68f3bad0068c44122e734367f64557112e058c8222e3fd3908e68402ce6d5`

Now as `createCipher` is deprecated what should I do with `createCipheriv` to give the same output as above.

I tried to pass `null` as `IV` to function `createCipheriv`, but I got the error `Missing IV for cipher aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1`

Comment: did you try passing iv as null [source](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) > `If the cipher does not need an initialization vector, iv may be null.`

Comment: @DhavalShah, I tried to pass iv = null, but it gave me error `Missing IV for cipher aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1.`

Comment: `createCipher` is deprecated because it uses a weak key derivation function (KDF) to derive the key / IV, namely `EVP_BytesToKey` from OpenSSL. `createCipheriv` on the other hand already uses the _final_ key / IV. Here you have the possibility to use a _secure_ KDF such as PBKDF2 with which you can derive key / IV in a secure way (if you need this at all). If you want to get the same result with `createCipheriv` as with `createCipher`, you would have to use the same weak KDF, which would leave the insecurity. What are the reasons for doing it this way? What is your use case?

Comment: @Topaco, The use case is I used to store everything encrypted in my database and that all were encrypted with `createCipher` in old days, so every time I need to query on any column I need to encrypt that value first and then query on the collection. So to get the records I need to encrypt to the same values using the `createCipheriv` function, which I encrypted and stored with the earlier function `createCipher`.

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense in the long term to migrate the old encrypted data.If you want to reproduce the `createCipher` functionality with `createCipheriv`, you need, as already mentioned, a NodeJS implementation of the KDF `EVP_BytesToKey`, e.g. [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evp_bytestokey). Not tested! As you can see in the documentation of [`createCipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options), MD5 is used, an iteration count of 1 and no salt. Everything terribly insecure. Thus, for security reasons this is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Finally I resolved the same using some hacks as below -

```
const bytesToKey = require('evp_bytestokey');

const encryptionToken = bytesToKey(SomePasswordString, null, 256, 16);


//Ciphering 
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1', encryptionToken.key, encryptionToken.iv);
return cipher.update(JSON.stringify(##VALUEtoENCRYPT##), 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');


//De-Ciphering 
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc-hmac-sha1', encryptionToken.key, encryptionToken.iv);
return JSON.parse(decipher.update(##VALUEtoDECRYPT##, 'hex', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8'));
```

Thanks to `@topaco` for suggesting me to use NPM package `evp_bytestokey`

Comment: I love you man.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right / good way to do it, we can use the same `key` and `iv` to return the same encrypted and decrypted values each time. And if you do not have a `key` and `iv` in mind, you can try using 0 filled buffers as `key` and `iv`.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var algo = 'aes-256-ctr';
var key = Buffer.alloc(32);
key.fill(0);
var iv = Buffer.alloc(16);
iv.fill(0);

const encrypt = (text) => {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algo, key, iv);
    var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'base64');
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return crypted
};

const decrypt = (text) => {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algo, key, iv);
    var crypted = decipher.update(text, 'base64', 'utf8');
    crypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return crypted;
};

var encrypted = encrypt('yourpassword'); 
console.log(encrypted); //pfq1CtIh+vraJ9Bw
var decrypted = decrypt('pfq1CtIh+vraJ9Bw');
console.log(decrypted); //yourpassword
```